# Firebase Retrieve specific data from listview and display it on text view

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the details of the item clicked by the user in the list view onto a text view. However for some reason, no matter which item I click, the text view will always display only one data from my database. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to do so. Please help me solve this problem. Let me know if there isn't enough information.

MainActivity:

```
private void showDetailsDialog(final String teamName){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final TextView textViewDetails = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDetails);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(teamName);
    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();

    databaseTeams.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                //Getting the data from snapshot
                Team team = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);

                //Adding it to a string
                String string =  "Team Name: "+team.getTeamName()+"\nSport: "+team.getTeamSport()+"\nTeam Leader: "+team.getTeamOwner()+
                        "\nDate: "+team.getDate()+"\nTime: "+team.getTime()+"\n\n";

                //Displaying it on textview
                textViewDetails.setText(string);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

}
```

Database:

It will always show "ping" details no matter which one I click.

[image]